# Redirecting using React Router shows blank page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, react-router, react-dom

I'm trying to build a simple example project where the user is redirected to the 'contact' page upon clicking a button, using React. I'm trying to achieve this by setting the value of a state property. When I run the code I have, it does change the browser address bar URL to that of the contact page, but does not seem to actually load the component - I get a blank page instead. If I manually navigate to that URL (http://localhost:3000/contact) I can see the contents.

Here are my `App.js` and `Contact.js` files -

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import Contact from './Contact';

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        redirect: false
    }

    setRedirect = () => {
        this.setState({
            redirect: true
        })
    }

    renderRedirect = () => {
        if (this.state.redirect) {
            return <Redirect to='/contact' />
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/contact' component={Contact} />
                </Switch>
                <div>
                    {this.renderRedirect()}
                    <button onClick={this.setRedirect}>Redirect</button>
                </div>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

**Contact.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Contact extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Contact Me</h2>
                <input type="text"></input>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Contact;
```

Using state isn't really a requirement for me, so other (preferably simpler) methods of redirection would be appreciated too.

Answer (score 3):

Since your button is nothing more than a link, you could replace it with:

```
<Link to="/contact">Redirect</Link>
```

There are many alternatives though, you could for example look into BrowserRouter's `browserHistory`:

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'

browserHistory.push("/contact")
```

Or perhaps `this.props.history.push("/contact")`.

There are pros and cons to every method, you'll have to look into each and see which you prefer.

Comment: Eventually I want to build a login form, where the user is redirected upon successful login. Thanks for the other suggestions, I'll look into them.

Comment: When I use `this.props.history.push()`, react gives me an error saying "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined". When I try to import `browserHistory`, it says "Attempted import error: 'browserHistory' is not exported from 'react-router'."

Comment: ```import {withRouter} from react-router-dom```
You can get access to the history object’s properties and the closest Route's match via the withRouter higher-order component. withRouter will pass updated match, location, and history props to the wrapped component whenever it renders.

Answer (score 1):

I got here for a similiar situation. It's possible use `withRouter` (https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) to handle that.

This example was tested with `"react": "^16.13.1"`,`"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"` and `"history": "^5.0.0"` into `"dependecies"` sections in **package.json** file.

In App.js I have the `BrowserRouter` (usually people import `BrowserRouter as Router`, I prefer work with original names) with Home and Contact.

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    BrowserRouter,
    Switch,
    Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Contact from "./pages/Contact";
class App extends Component
{
    // stuff...
    render()
    {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/contact">
                        <Contact />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/">
                        <Home />
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

**ASIDE 1**: *The `Route` with `path="/contact"` is placed before `path="/"` because `Switch` render the first match, so put `Home` at the end. If you have `path="/something"` and `path="/something/:id"` place the more specific route (with `/:id` in this case) before. (https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch)*

**ASIDE 2**: *I'm using class component but I believe (I didn't test it) a functional component will also work.*

In Home.js and Contact.js I use `withRouter` associated with `export` keyword. This makes Home and Contact components receive the `history` object of `BrowserRouter` via `props`. Use method `push()` to add "/contact" and "/" to the history stack. (https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history).

**Home.js**

```
import React from "react";
import {
    withRouter
} from "react-router-dom";

export const Home = ( props ) =>
{
    return (
        <div>
            Home!
            <button
                onClick={ () => props.history.push( "/contact" ) }
            >
                Get in Touch
            <button>
        </div>
    );
}
export default withRouter( Home );
```

**Contact.js**

```
import React from "react";
import {
    withRouter
} from "react-router-dom";

export const Contact = ( props ) =>
{
    return (
        <div>
            Contact!
            <button
                onClick={ () => props.history.push( "/" ) }
            >
                Go Home
            <button>
        </div>
    );
}
export default withRouter( Contact );
```

Particularly, I'm using also in a `BackButton` component with `goBack()` to navigate backwards:

**BackButton.js**

```
import React from "react";
import {
    withRouter
} from "react-router-dom";

export const BackButton = ( props ) =>
{
    return (
        <button
            onClick={ () => props.history.goBack() }
        >
            Go back
        <button>
    );
}
export default withRouter( BackButton );
```

So I could modify the `Contact` to:

**Contact.js** (with BackButton)

```
import React from "react";
import BackButton from "../components/BackButton";

export const Contact = ( props ) =>
{
    return (
        <div>
            Contact!
            <BackButton />
        </div>
    );
}
export default Contact; // now I'm not using history in this file.
// the navigation responsability is inside BackButton component.
```

Above was the best solution for me. Other possible solutions are:

- useHistory Hook (https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks)
- work with `Router` instead `BrowserRouter` - (https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Router)